# Unity : Boat drowned slowly after moving

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

This is the picture of my boat after move just a bit. And it slowly drowned at back:
[image: Image.]

And this is the setting of my boat. I have try to change the value in that, but seems did not give any effect:
[image: Image2.]

Boat :

- Mesh Renderer
- Rigidbody
- Mesh Collider
- Float Object Script
- Boat Controller Script

Lake :

- Water Basic Plane
- Mesh Renderer
- Water Basic Script

Coding for WaterBasic (Lake) :

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Water
{
    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    public class WaterBasic : MonoBehaviour
    {
        void Update()
        {
            Renderer r = GetComponent<Renderer>();
            if (!r)
            {
                return;
            }
            Material mat = r.sharedMaterial;
            if (!mat)
            {
                return;
            }

            Vector4 waveSpeed = mat.GetVector("WaveSpeed");
            float waveScale = mat.GetFloat("_WaveScale");
            float t = Time.time / 20.0f;

            Vector4 offset4 = waveSpeed * (t * waveScale);
            Vector4 offsetClamped = new Vector4(Mathf.Repeat(offset4.x, 1.0f), Mathf.Repeat(offset4.y, 1.0f),
                Mathf.Repeat(offset4.z, 1.0f), Mathf.Repeat(offset4.w, 1.0f));
            mat.SetVector("_WaveOffset", offsetClamped);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for FloatObjectScript (Boat) :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class FloatObjectScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float waterLevel = 0.0f;
    public float floatThreshold = 2.0f;
    public float waterDensity = 0.125f;
    public float downForce = 4.0f;

    private float forceFactor;
    private Vector3 floatForce;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        forceFactor = 1.0f - ((transform.position.y - waterLevel) / floatThreshold);

        if (forceFactor > 0.0f)
        {
            floatForce = -Physics.gravity * GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass * (forceFactor - GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y * waterDensity);
            floatForce += new Vector3(0.0f, -downForce * GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass, 0.0f);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForceAtPosition(floatForce, transform.position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more details on what it is that is making the boat move in the first place? Is it purely physics based? Are you using a script? Does it have any animations? Does the water have a collider? And what components are on the boat's parent gameObject?

Comment: i import the boat from the asset.
boat :
i. rigidbody
ii. Float object script
iii. Boat controller script
iv. Mesh collider

water :
i. Water Basic script

Comment: Hi, I see you are using the [tag:UnityScript] tag, please note that this is (as explained in the tag info) a deprecated scripting language made by Unity, and not an encompassing term for all scripts in Unity. Your question is about C#. Please only use this tag if you're working on legacy code using the actual language UnityScript. This keeps the questions and tags in line with each other :)

Comment: okay. thank you for informed me. will delete it.

Comment: There are two different approaches I would take here. 1. Freeze the boats rigid-body rotation so that it won't tip at all. 2. In the boats script have it constantly check whether the boat's rotation goes beyond say 10 degrees, if it goes beyond that then add some torque (rotational force) to the boat to make it tip the other way.This will also give the boat a nice rocking motion. Edit: A 3rd approach would be to animate the boat. Animations are done relative to a gameObject's parent so by animating just the child to stay upright it won't have any affect on the parent's movement.

Answer (score 0):

Try decreasing the mass. since force required to float is directly proportional to mass.

Comment: it doesnt give any effect

Comment: can you share floating script

Comment: okay. already add it on my question. sorry, i just didnt know how to add at the comment since im new in here.

Comment: change the drag of rigidbody component to 1 from 0.1